# How to define the API Url's in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, code-organization

I want to define the API URL's in a single header file, like

```
#define BASE_URL                    @"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api"

#define POSTS                       BASE_URL @"/user_posts"
#define kAPI_GET_POSTS_LIST_URL     POSTS
#define kAPI_ADD_LIKE_URL(id)       POSTS @"/" id @"/like"
```

......

But it does not work when the 'id' is dynamic. 
Is there any better ways to organize API Url's?

Comment: I'd recommend not using #define. There's not a particularly good reason to do so versus providing an NSString const.

Comment: This and only this is the correct answer.

Comment: A design suggestion: make an object that handles your API requests and make a method to make API URLs and use NSString* const for constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bari or ;),
You can define like this

```
#define BASE_URL                    @"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api"

#define POSTS                       BASE_URL @"/user_posts"
#define kAPI_GET_POSTS_LIST_URL     POSTS
#define kAPI_ADD_LIKE_URL(id)       [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/like", POSTS, id]
```

And use it

```
NSString *someId = @"5";
kAPI_ADD_LIKE_URL(someId);
```

Comment: mersi;) but in this case it is necessary to write everywhere [NSString ......] that is not very nice ... but it works))

Comment: yes, if the string is generated at runtime, than it's can't be processed at compile-time. So when you declare strings in code, they are placed into .DATA segment in you binary, and they can be concated by space, but at runtime you need to call a runtime method, which will construct a new string. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
#define kAPI_ADD_LIKE_URL(id)       [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%d/lik",POSTS,id]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
#define BASE_URL                    @"http://www.........."
#define POST                        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/user_posts",BASE_URL]
#define kAPI_GET_POSTS_LIST_URL     POSTS
#define kAPI_ADD_LIKE_URL(uri)      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/like",POSTS,uri]
```

Hope this will help :)